# Can't import excel data in Laravel 8. am new to it

Tags: php, laravel

**Am new to laravel8 trying to import data from excel sheet to the database, here is my code in the import class its not passing not giving any error. so the database has relationship am trying to import the data and make sure the relationships are considered so that l shouldn't have any problems **

```
   <?php
   
   namespace App\Imports;
   
   use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
   use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
   use App\Models\District;
   use App\Models\Organisation;
   use App\Models\FocalPerson;
   use App\Models\Ta;
   use App\Models\Location;
   use App\Models\Service;
   use App\Models\Category;
   use App\Models\Type;
   
   
   
   
   class InformationImport implements ToCollection
   {
       /**
       * @param array $row
       *
       * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
       */
       public function collection(Collection $rows)
       {
           foreach ($rows as $row) 
           {
               $instance_id = $row[1];
               $organisation_name = $row[2];
               $service_provider = $row[3];
               $catchment_area = $row[4];
               $organisation_type = $row[5];
               $district_name = $row[6];
               $organisation_web = $row[7];
               $primary_name = $row[8];
               $primary_title = $row[9];
               $primary_number = $row[10];
               $primary_email = $row[11];
               $secondary_name = $row[12];
               $secondary_number = $row[13];
               $secondary_title = $row[14];
               $secondary_email = $row[15];
               $services_name = $row[16];
               $location = explode(',',$row[17],2);
               return $location;
               $location_altitude = $row[18];
               $location_accuracy = $row[19];
               $comments_distance = $row[20];
               $data_comments = $row[21];
   
              $ta = Ta::where('name','like','%'.$row[4] .'%')->whereHas('district', 
               function($query) use($district_name){
                  $query->where('name','like','%'.$district_name .'%');
               })->get();
               if(!$ta){
                   $district = District::firstOrCreate([
                       'name' => $row[6]
                   ]);
                   $ta = new Ta;
                   $ta->name = $row[4];
                   $district->tas()->save($ta);
               }
               $gvh = Gvh::firstOrCreate([
                   'name' => 'unknown',
                   'ta_id' => $ta->id
               ]);
               $location = Location::firstOrCreate([
                   'latitude'=>$location,
                   'longitude'=>$location,
                   'gvh_id'=> $gvh->id
               ]);
               $service = Service::firstOrCreate([
                   'name'=>$services_name
               ]);
               $category = Category::firstOrCreate([
                   'name'=>'unknown'
               ]);
               $type = Type::firstOrCreate([
                   'name'=>$organisation_type
               ]);
               $organisation = Organisation::firstOrCreate([
                    'name'=> $organisation_name,
                    'location_id' => $location->id,
                    'organisation_type_id' => $type->id,
                    'organisation_category_id' => $category->id
               ]); 
               $focalperson =FocalPerson::firstOrCreate([
                   'title'=>  $primary_title, $secondary_title,
                   'name' => $primary_name,$secondary_name,
                   'phonenumber'=>$primary_number,$secondary_number,
                   'email'=> $primary_email, $secondary_email
               ]);
           }
       }
       
   }
```

**below is my controller class. in the controller that's the code l have because it wasn't bringing anything l had to write it in that way and see if it will be able to output the messages **

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Imports\InformationImport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

class InformationController extends Controller
{
 
 public function import(Request $request) 
 {
     //Excel::import(new InformationImport, $request->file); 
     //return response()->json(['message' => 'Your data imported successfully !'], 200);
     if ($request->ajax()) {

         try {
 
             Excel::import(new InformationImport, $request->file);
 
             return response()->json(['message' => 'Your data imported successfully !'], 200);
 
         } catch (ValidationException $ex) {
 
             $failures = $ex->failures();
             foreach ($failures as $failure) {
                 return response()->json(['message' => 'Row - ' . $failure->row() . ', ' . $failure->errors()[0]], 500);
             }
 
         }
 
     }
     return response()->json(['message' => 'Something went wrong !'], 500);
 }
 
}
```

Comment: any errors in laravel.log?

Comment: No errors shown

Answer (score 0):

```
   public function import(Request $request) 
   {
       ini_set('max_execution_time', -1);
       ini_set('memory_limit ', -1);
      
       if ($request->ajax()) {

          try {
             $file_content = $request->file('excel');
             $file_name = time() . '.xlsx';

             Storage::disk('local')->putFileAs('public', $file_content, $file_name);
             $url = "/app/public/" . $file_name;
             $path = storage_path() . $url;
             Excel::import(new InformationImport, $path);
 
             return response()->json(['message' => 'Your data imported successfully !'], 200);
 
         } catch (ValidationException $ex) {
 
             $failures = $ex->failures();
             foreach ($failures as $failure) {
                 return response()->json(['message' => 'Row - ' . $failure->row() . ', ' . $failure->errors()[0]], 500);
             }
         }
      }
      return response()->json(['message' => 'Something went wrong !'], 500);
     }
```

Comment: Please enable your laravel debugger and check the error

Comment: Alryt does it still work the same using api...because am using restful api with postman

Answer (score 0):

This is sample and runnable code. Please refer

```
In Your Controller 


public function import(Request $request){

        $this->validate($request,[
            'file'=> 'required|mimes:xlsx,csv'
        ]);

        try{
            Excel::import(new CannedResponseImport,request()->file('file'));
             
            return back()
                ->withSuccess('Data imported successfully.');
        }catch(\Exception $ex){
            return back()
                ->withError('Someting went wrong please try again.');
        } 
    }
```

```html
In your Import

<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\CannedResponses; 

use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;  

class CannedResponseImport implements ToCollection,WithHeadingRow 
{
     
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {  
       
        foreach ($rows as $row) { 
           
            if($row->filter()->isNotEmpty()){  
                if(!empty($row['business_type_id']) && !empty($row['brand_id']) && !empty($row['contact_reason_id'])
                    && !empty($row['contact_sub_reason_id']) && !empty($row['personality_type_id']) && !empty($row['response_segment_id'])
                    && !empty($row['response_tone_id']) && !empty($row['nature_conversation_id']) && !empty($row['canned_response'])
                ){ 
                    $id = CannedResponses::insertGetId([
                        'business_type_id'      => $row['business_type_id'],
                        'brand_id'              => $row['brand_id'],
                        'contact_reason_id'     => $row['contact_reason_id'], 
                        'contact_sub_reason_id' => $row['contact_sub_reason_id'], 
                        'nature_conversation_id' => $row['nature_conversation_id'], 
                        'personality_type_id'   => $row['personality_type_id'],
                        'response_segment_id'   => $row['response_segment_id'],
                        'response_tone_id'      => $row['response_tone_id'],
                        'message'               => $row['canned_response']
                    ]); 
                   
                }
            } 
        }  
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).